# installing apache thrift on windows

Tags: windows, thrift

I've been trying to install apache thrift the whole day could anyone provide a guide with simple instructions because i did not get anything from the docus so i've downloaded the .exe file i've tried to run/build/install it but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://thrift.apache.org/ has a tutorial and a "getting started" section. I would recommend to start there.

Comment: It is a standalone cmdline EXE. There is no installer. Aside from it, could you please try to narrow down "does not work?"

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple.

First, download the thrift standalone exe from their website. It is a pre-compiled exe and you don't need anything after downloading it. Actually ignore the second step in docs.

The way that thrift work is:

You write a thrift file in which you indicate which functions will be implemented/called and which data types will be transferred.

Then Thrift compiler can compile the thrift file to your target languages.

You use generated files in your server/client apps. The server must implement functionalities you specified and the client would call those functions.

To achieve this create a .thrift file and put it on the same directory as thrift exe file is. and after writing your functionality in .thrift file enter `thrift --gen <language> <Thrift filename>` in a command line(PowerShell, cmd, etc.) and you will get your language files that you can copy and use in your projects.

This is actually inspired by [this video](https://youtu.be/nNQSfRwT0Do) and I hope it help to start with thrift.